# Modal Popup is getting closing when am trying to append the data to its body in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi friends am trying to append a some data to my modal popup, which comes from the partial view on clicking some button, on clicking the Next button another question should be appended to the popup, and should not close it until user closes it manually, this is a simple test conducting application

```
@model List<Vulpith.Models.View.Test.AdaptabilityViewModel><div>
@foreach (var a in Model)
{
    <div>@a.QDescription</div>
}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="StartTest()">Next</button>
```

am appending above content to the following model on ajax submission

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="appendquestion">

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="StartTest()">Start Test</button>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

following is the controller

```
    public ActionResult _QuestionView()
    {

        return PartialView(new AdaptabilityTestTrans().Get());
    }
```

and my ajax submission is

```
<script>
function StartTest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $("baseUrl").html() + "Test/_QuestionView",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            $('#appendquestion').html(data);
            $('#myModal').modal(show);



        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Remove the `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute (that closes you modal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `data-dismiss="modal"` from `modal-footer`. As you call `StartTest()`by clicking the Start Button, `data-dismiss` gets trigged and closes the modal.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"onclick="StartTest()">Start Test</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery.noConflict() before $('#myModal').modal(show);
and run your code it will work